# Load former version into working tree and start new branch

Tags: egit

I just started working with Egit and I don't understand how to jump back to a former version of a file (or project) and start a new branch from there.

**Example:**

I create a single text file in an Egit shared project:

```
Version 0.98
Version 0.99
Version 1.00 First Release
Version 1.01
Version 1.02
```

I commited after each line (i.e. five times). All is done in the master branch.

My goal now is to load *Version 1.00* back in the working tree and start a new branch from there.

Maybe I misunderstand some Egit principles but I think that this is a common way to use code version control. So how can I do this in Egit?

I use *Eclipse Indigo (3.7)* and *Egit 1.0*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click on the commit in the History view, which made Version 1.00, and select Create branch. In the dialog keep the checkbox "Checkout new branch" selected, type a name for the branch and hit Finish.

Comment: "Just click on the commit in the history view" - what do you mean exactly? In the history view I see "master head V1.02" only. I tried the "Show all changes ..." buttons, but with no effect.

Comment: If you really made 5 separate commits, then in the history view should be that 5 commits (right click on your project, and select Team -> Show in history). Can you make a screenshot of your history view?

Comment: I checked it again with a new project. Now the history view shows me all commits. Don't know what went wrong, but now your solution works. Thanks!